# Create a "tail" for an object that is orbiting

Tags: javascript, canvas, orbital-mechanics

**Edit**

Here is a JSFiddle with the code for the "tail" function commenting out.[Solar System JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Grabow/dmqv6cg2/1/)

I have this object I am working on that has an object orbiting a center mass. That works perfectly.
[image: small red planet orbiting sun]

I am now trying to add a trailing line or "tail" that follows behind the planet.
My tail object looks like this:

```
function Tail(maxLength){
  this.points = [];
  this.maxLength = maxLength;
  this.addPoint = function(point){
    for(var i = Math.min(maxLength, this.points.length); i < maxLength; i++){
        this.points[i] = this.points[i - 1];
    }

    this.points[0] = point;
 }
 this.draw = function(ctx){
    for(var i = 1; Math.min(maxLength, this.points.length); i++){
        if(i < maxLength - 20){
            ctx.globalAlpha = 1;
        } else {
            ctx.globalAlpha = (this.maxLength - i) / 20;
        }

        ctx.beginPath();
        ctx.moveTo(this.points[i - 1].x, this.points[i - 1].y);
        ctx.lineTo(this.points[i].x, this.points[i].y);
        ctx.stroke();
    }

    ctx.globalAlpha = 1;
  }
}
```

The addPoint function takes an object that looks like '{x: currentX, y: currentY}
currentX and currentY are the x and y point of the object when ever it gets called.

I am lost on how I need to add the point to the points array and then draw based on those coordinates.

Comment: Try creating a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) for us so we can run your code and make suggestions where necessary.

Comment: The loop conditions look odd.  Is your intent to count back from the current position?  Shouldn't you *decrement* the loop variable, I?  Consider using Array.slice()

Comment: I updated the post to have a link to a jsfiddle of the code running the simulation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I modified your version to working condition

```js
var canvas, width, height, ctx;
var bodies = [];

function init(){
    canvas = document.getElementById("space-time");
    width = window.innerWidth;
    height = window.innerHeight;
    canvas.width = width;
    canvas.height = height;
    ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');

    createBodies();

    setInterval(function(){
        updateSystem();
        updateBodies(0.01);
        ctx.clearRect(0, 0, width, height);
        drawBodies();
    }, 10);
}

function createBodies(){
    bodies.push(new Body((this.width / 2) - 250, (this.height / 2) - 300, 200, 0, 1, 10, "#14c71d", true));
    bodies.push(new Body((this.width / 2) + 100, (this.height / 2) + 100, 350, 0, 1, 5, "#de2d16", true));
    bodies.push(new Body(this.width / 2, this.height / 2, 0, 0, 1000000, 30, "#FF8501", false)); //sun
}

function drawBodies(){
    for(var i = 0; i < bodies.length; i++){
        bodies[i].draw(ctx);
    }
}

function updateBodies(dt){
    for(var i = 0; i < bodies.length; i++){
        bodies[i].update(dt);
    }
}

function updateSystem(){
    var G = 10;
    for(var i = 0; i < bodies.length; i++){
        for(var j = 0; j < bodies.length; j++){
            if(i === j) continue;
            var b1 = bodies[i];
            var b2 = bodies[j];

            var dist = Math.sqrt((b1.x - b2.x) * (b1.x - b2.x) + (b1.y - b2.y) * (b1.y - b2.y));
            var force = G * (b1.m * b2.m) / dist / dist;
            var nx = (b2.x - b1.x) / dist;
            var ny = (b2.y - b1.y) / dist;

            b1.ax += nx * force / b1.m;
            b1.ay += ny * force / b1.m;

            b2.ax -= nx * force / b2.m;
            b2.ay -= ny * force / b2.m;
        }
    }
}

function Body(x, y, v, angle, mass, radius, color, hasTail){
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;
    this.vx = v * Math.cos(angle);
    this.vy = v * Math.sin(angle);
    this.m = mass;
    this.radius = radius;
    this.color = color;
    this.ax = 0;
    this.ay = 0;

    if (hasTail) {
        this.tail = new Tail(50);
    }
    
    this.update = function(dt){
        this.vx += this.ax * dt;
        this.vy += this.ay * dt;
        this.x += this.vx * dt;
        this.y += this.vy * dt;
        this.ax = 0;
        this.ay = 0;

        if(this.tail){
            this.tail.addPoint({x: this.x, y: this.y});
        }
    }

    this.draw = function(ctx){
        ctx.strokeStyle = this.color;
        ctx.fillStyle = this.color;
        ctx.shadowColor = this.color;
        ctx.shadowBlur = 5;
        if(this.tail){
            this.tail.draw(ctx);
        }
        ctx.beginPath();
        ctx.arc(this.x, this.y, this.radius, 0, 6.28);
        ctx.fill();
    }
}

function Tail(maxLength){
    this.points = [];
    this.maxLength = maxLength;
    this.addPoint = point => {
        this.points = [point].concat(this.points).slice(0, this.maxLength);
    }
    this.draw = function(ctx){
        for(var i = 1; i < this.points.length; i++){
            ctx.beginPath();
            if(i < maxLength - 20){
                ctx.globalAlpha = 1;
            } else {
                ctx.globalAlpha = (this.maxLength - i) / 20;
            }
            ctx.moveTo(this.points[i - 1].x, this.points[i - 1].y);
            ctx.lineTo(this.points[i].x, this.points[i].y);
            ctx.stroke();
        }
        ctx.globalAlpha = 1;
    }
}
```

```css
#space-time {
    background-color: #1a1a1c;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Solar System AJ</title>
</head>
<body onload="init();">
    <canvas id="space-time"></canvas>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Wow, very elegant solution. No idea where I was going with my attempt.

Answer (score 1):

You can visualisate the track of objects, if you fill frame with background with low opacity instead of clearing it:

```js
var canvas, width, height, ctx;
var bodies = [];

function init(){
    canvas = document.getElementById("space-time");
    width = window.innerWidth;
    height = window.innerHeight;
    canvas.width = width;
    canvas.height = height;
    ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');

    createBodies();

    setInterval(function(){
        updateSystem();
        updateBodies(0.01);
        
        // ctx.clearRect(0, 0, width, height);

        // All magic here:
        ctx.fillStyle = `rgba(0, 0, 0, .05)`;
        ctx.shadowBlur = 0;
        ctx.fillRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);

        drawBodies();
    }, 10);
}

function createBodies(){
    bodies.push(new Body((this.width / 2) - 250, (this.height / 2) - 300, 200, 0, 1, 10, "#14c71d", true));
    bodies.push(new Body((this.width / 2) + 100, (this.height / 2) + 100, 350, 0, 1, 5, "#de2d16", true));
    bodies.push(new Body(this.width / 2, this.height / 2, 0, 0, 1000000, 30, "#FF8501", false)); //sun
}

function drawBodies(){
    for(var i = 0; i < bodies.length; i++){
        bodies[i].draw(ctx);
    }
}

function updateBodies(dt){
    for(var i = 0; i < bodies.length; i++){
        bodies[i].update(dt);
    }
}

function updateSystem(){
    var G = 10;
    for(var i = 0; i < bodies.length; i++){
        for(var j = 0; j < bodies.length; j++){
            if(i === j) continue;
            var b1 = bodies[i];
            var b2 = bodies[j];

            var dist = Math.sqrt((b1.x - b2.x) * (b1.x - b2.x) + (b1.y - b2.y) * (b1.y - b2.y));
            var force = G * (b1.m * b2.m) / dist / dist;
            var nx = (b2.x - b1.x) / dist;
            var ny = (b2.y - b1.y) / dist;

            b1.ax += nx * force / b1.m;
            b1.ay += ny * force / b1.m;

            b2.ax -= nx * force / b2.m;
            b2.ay -= ny * force / b2.m;
        }
    }
}

function Body(x, y, v, angle, mass, radius, color, hasTail){
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;
    this.vx = v * Math.cos(angle);
    this.vy = v * Math.sin(angle);
    this.m = mass;
    this.radius = radius;
    this.color = color;
    this.ax = 0;
    this.ay = 0;

    this.update = function(dt){
        this.vx += this.ax * dt;
        this.vy += this.ay * dt;
        this.x += this.vx * dt;
        this.y += this.vy * dt;
        this.ax = 0;
        this.ay = 0;
    }

    this.draw = function(ctx){
        ctx.beginPath();
        ctx.arc(this.x, this.y, this.radius, 0, 6.28);
        ctx.strokeStyle = this.color;
        ctx.fillStyle = this.color;
        ctx.shadowColor = this.color;
        ctx.shadowBlur = 5;
        ctx.fill();
    }
}
```

```css
#space-time {
    background-color: #1a1a1c;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Solar System AJ</title>
</head>
<body onload="init();">
    <canvas id="space-time"></canvas>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: This will blur any moving thing in the canvas

Comment: @JonasGrumann This not blur anything. Objects blurred in original code, I had to specially reset the blur before filling the background

Comment: Hmmm, this is an interesting approach. Would this style be able to be just a line that follows the path instead of a circle? Looks like you could change the fillRect to a stroke?